# Não consigo invocar o "innerHTML" para alterar o HTML de um elemento. Por quê?

Tags: javascript, html

Neste código eu estou testando para que o usuário coloque duas notas e o JS execute o cálculo e imprima na tela para que o usuário veja. Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer com que o resultado da média apareça na tela, mas estou conseguindo fazer com que ela apareça como alerta. Poderiam me ajudar?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sistema de Aprovação/Reprovação</h1>

    <div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Digite a primeira nota</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota1">
          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Digite a segunda nota</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
          
        </div>
        <button onclick="CalculaMedia()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular a Média</button>
      </form>
      <div id='res'>A média do aluno é:</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function CalculaMedia() {
            var tn1 = document.getElementById('nota1');
            var tn2 = document.getElementById('nota2');
            var res = document.getElementById('res');
            var n1 = Number(tn1.value);
            var n2 = Number(tn2.value);
            var m = (n1 + n2)/2;
            
            alert(`A média do aluno é: ${m}`);
            res.innerHTML(`A média do aluno é: ${m}`)
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Veja no seu código:

> ```
> res.innerHTML(`A média do aluno é: ${m}`);
> ```

`innerHTML` não é uma função para ser chamada (note os parênteses, que denotam a [sintaxe de aplicação de funções em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions)).

Note que um `TypeError` é lançado quando você tenta invocá-lo:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: res.innerHTML is not a function
> ```

O [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) uma propriedade. Isso significa que, para alterá-la, você deve *definir*, através do operador de atribuição (`=`), um novo valor.

Para corrigir, basta utilizar o operador de atribuição:

```
res.innerHTML = `A média do aluno é: ${m}`;
```

Comment: Luiz Felipe, fiz a alteração que você me detalhou e aconteceu o seguinte: ele escreve a resposta na tela mas ela pisca e logo some. Já tinha acontecido isso outras vezes, agora mesmo não consigo resolver esse problema

Comment: Isso é porque o formulário está sendo submetido quando você aperta o botão. Para resolver isso, adicione o atributo `onsubmit="return false"` no formulário (tem outras formas de se resolver, mas, no seu caso, essa é a mais simples). Uma outra opção é alterar o atributo `type="submit"` por `type="button"` no botão.

Comment: Luiz Felipe, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda o problema foi resolvido!

Comment: @LucasMendes, nesse caso você pode marcar esta resposta como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. :-)